# OSX Server MDM Push Failing

Tags: ios, macos, mdm

We have been using an Apple Mini running OS X server for about 2 years now to manage about 200 iPads.  Our certificates and provisioning profiles where expiring so we updated all of them including our push certificate and signing certificate.  As far as I can tell we have everything current and valid (provision profiles installed on the tablets also say that they are valid)

The problem is that for some reason about half of the iPads are receiving the push but not installing the apps.  The other half receive them fine everything installs.  I have a brand new iPad pro that I just provisioned that is not installing the apps.  I checked the logs and the iPad pro is receiving the push however it's crashing when it tries to install.  Not sure why this is happening... here are the logs

```
Jan  8 16:01:12 Testing-ipad com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]

    (com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmd[290]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Jan  8 16:01:12 Testing-ipad diagnosticd[79] <Error>: unable to find offset 0x829939a4 in shared cache for arch 'arm64'
Jan  8 16:01:12 Testing-ipad ReportCrash[291] <Notice>: platform_thread_get_unique_id matched 64805
Jan  8 16:01:12 Testing-ipad ReportCrash[291] <Notice>: Formulating report for corpse[290] mdmd
Jan  8 16:01:12 Testing-ipad ReportCrash[291] <Warning>: saved type '109_mdmd' report (9 of max 25) as /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/mdmd_2016-01-08-160112_Testing-ipad.ips}






Incident Identifier: 2552DD95-4447-4BFB-AF05-8DA62FCEF7E1
CrashReporter Key:   06256ea4bd830d56fa56426743f407faf9cc028a
Hardware Model:      iPad6,7
Process:             mdmd [277]
Path:                /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/Support/mdmd
Identifier:          mdmd
Version:             ???
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]


Date/Time:           2016-01-08 14:28:36.36 -0500
Launch Time:         2016-01-08 14:28:35.35 -0500
OS Version:          iOS 9.2 (13C75)
Report Version:      105


Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0


Filtered syslog:
None found


Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
0.202314     CFNetwork                 0x00000001834f184c TCP Conn 0x15ce3f290 SSL Handshake DONE
0.342485     CFNetwork                 0x00000001834f175c TCP Conn 0x15ce3f290 starting SSL negotiation
0.343163     CFNetwork                 0x0000000183593104 TCP Conn 0x15ce3f290 complete. fd: 6, err: 0
0.344204     CFNetwork                 0x0000000183594630 TCP Conn 0x15ce3f290 event 1. err: 0
0.408975     CFNetwork                 0x0000000183594708 TCP Conn 0x15ce3f290 started
0.411702     CFNetwork                 0x00000001835e98f8 Creating default cookie storage with process/bundle identifier
0.411702     CFNetwork                 0x00000001835e9888 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
0.411702     CFNetwork                 0x000000018363b558 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton






Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182dfeebc CFStringGetLength + 20
1   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182ef3b24 _CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath + 80
2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182ef3b24 _CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath + 80
3   libmis.dylib                   0x00000001857cb50c 0x1857c8000 + 13580
4   libmis.dylib                   0x00000001857cbd4c 0x1857c8000 + 15692
5   libmis.dylib                   0x00000001857ccf64 MISAppApprovalState + 204
6   MDM                           0x00000001975d6ee8 -[LSApplicationProxy(MCMISValidation) isMISAuthorized] + 80
7   MDM                           0x00000001975d6e7c +[LSApplicationProxy(MCMISValidation) applicationProxyIsMISAuthorizedForBundleID:] + 56
8   MDM                           0x00000001975e29a0 -[MCMDMParser _managedApplicationList:] + 1540
9   MDM                           0x00000001975d8ebc -[MCMDMParser _processRequest:accessRights:assertion:completionBlock:] + 1260
10  MDM                           0x00000001975d8954 -[MCMDMParser processRequest:accessRights:assertion:completionBlock:] + 2752
11  mdmd                           0x000000010003bad8 0x100030000 + 47832
12  mdmd                           0x000000010003adf8 0x100030000 + 44536
13  libdispatch.dylib             0x000000018296d630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
14  libdispatch.dylib             0x000000018296d5f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
15  libdispatch.dylib             0x0000000182972cf8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
16  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182ed0bb0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
17  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182ecea18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
18  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182dfd680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
19  Foundation                     0x00000001837f521c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
20  mdmd                           0x000000010003363c 0x100030000 + 13884
21  libdyld.dylib                 0x000000018299e8b8 start + 4


Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000182abcb6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81020 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000182abcb6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81020 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000182abd4fc kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x000000018298094c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib             0x000000018296f7bc _dispatch_source_invoke + 0


Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000182abcb6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81020 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000182abcb6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81020 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000182abcb6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81020 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000182aa14bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000182aa1338 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182ed0ac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182ece7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182dfd680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   Foundation                     0x00000001837f521c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
6   Foundation                     0x0000000183816368 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   ManagedConfiguration           0x00000001858af728 -[MCWorkerThread main] + 232
8   Foundation                     0x00000001838dbc40 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b83b28 _pthread_body + 156
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b83a8c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81028 thread_start + 4


Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000182aa14bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000182aa1338 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182ed0ac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182ece7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182dfd680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   CFNetwork                     0x000000018356d434 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6   Foundation                     0x00000001838dbc40 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b83b28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b83a8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81028 thread_start + 4


Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000182abcb6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81020 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 10 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000182abc368 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182ed7028 __CFSocketManager + 648
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b83b28 _pthread_body + 156
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b83a8c _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000182b81028 thread_start + 4


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000182f8d660  x10: 0x000000000015d400  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x00105e0000105e00  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000300000  x15: 0x0000000000040000
   x16: 0x00000000000001de  x17: 0x00000001843e2808  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x9700a902e7661174  x23: 0x00000001a0f8a0b0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x000000015ce4a780  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016fdce1a0  fp: 0x000000016fdce140   lr: 0x0000000182ef3b24
    sp: 0x000000016fdce130   pc: 0x0000000182dfeebc cpsr: 0x60000000


Binary Images:
0x100030000 - 0x100043fff mdmd arm64  <8b831df50cf53896a791f2a6319fc4ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/Support/mdmd
0x1200fc000 - 0x12012bfff dyld arm64  <9e98992ceed735e2ac4784cb28efe7c1> /usr/lib/dyld
0x182508000 - 0x182509fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <c4cd04b37e5f34698856a9384aefff40> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x18250c000 - 0x18255ffff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <d430d0ad16893b76bbc52468f65d5906> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x182560000 - 0x18257ffff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <1c0a8ef87e8c37b2a577dc1a44e2b16e> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x182580000 - 0x1828ecfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <da8e482b3e7d3c40a798a0c86a3d6890> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1828f0000 - 0x1828f4fff libcache.dylib arm64  <242f50f854a1301fa6f76b4531101238> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1828f8000 - 0x182903fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <f995fe44b0483f699bf9cfb570726bb3> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x182904000 - 0x182907fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <516b8400a98f3a4fb8f82780faca4b31> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x182908000 - 0x18290ffff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <c027b29d770e3a5e83aa48463916d3ed> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x182910000 - 0x18296bfff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <7afbc1f2b41b33f8a33ffa4701f534a9> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x18296c000 - 0x18299afff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <aa5aa53cebb13e23a840ac24e4380c81> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x18299c000 - 0x18299efff libdyld.dylib arm64  <ec4f964fd5e1365e8d8f4560b473cd01> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1829a0000 - 0x1829a0fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <aec3e1f1241e33a888763b2b3d54fc16> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x1829a4000 - 0x1829a8fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <c0a027eb0fdf34c4948a7a579754bb94> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x1829ac000 - 0x1829adfff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <2fb2b791a3453c019640b22cee6a0c00> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x1829b0000 - 0x1829c6fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <2373ea047a7c305583665937d3223d8b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x1829c8000 - 0x1829c9fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <294794ae7146331c8fd65a1ba652e7a4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1829cc000 - 0x182a4bfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <880a61b1eb96367f9bd7af9ec768c89b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x182a4c000 - 0x182a4ffff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <03109db3910b3d1db039296a8dcf3a6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x182a50000 - 0x182a52fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <fe2c6b6a57b6325887f02a3c867d36bf> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x182a54000 - 0x182a55fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <4bfbf0b2029f31299048d8aa82f50cf4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x182a58000 - 0x182a6efff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <a920142634313a95ad276a8e7ce041fc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x182a70000 - 0x182a78fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <aad8313dc34138e58674de8b37c8f823> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x182a7c000 - 0x182a9dfff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <c38ce7aacdf33d4081b7a526c8c3034e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x182aa0000 - 0x182ac1fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <3ba792d0972e3ec4b335bdb29dfce24b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x182ac4000 - 0x182ae0fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <784c81a596ec3863bbb18d2c6d57d1ce> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x182ae4000 - 0x182afdfff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <d540cfed29133811b05483d34c1d1b12> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x182b00000 - 0x182b5ffff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <8668f3c7d2583a858e982e431ff0029b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x182b60000 - 0x182b68fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <9294202d3e963025b416a89d70a0a9f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x182b6c000 - 0x182b76fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <dd38cc9e177a31f1820c306f9a5cdb90> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x182b78000 - 0x182b7dfff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <7ad36a3f683830338c1023238ee36e2d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x182b80000 - 0x182b88fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <95b8ce5f94ed34a98e0d76e96b7b6356> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x182b8c000 - 0x182b8efff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <f2905ac2a7033d599b43d6fe9ec21228> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x182b90000 - 0x182ba0fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <98a1bfbd6dad36298c4aa7e1c8c6892e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x182ba4000 - 0x182ba9fff libunwind.dylib arm64  <667befcaf5f339fb885e77ce99512fca> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x182bac000 - 0x182bacfff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <0735d1ebbd123718a8f17eb113615d6d> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x182bb0000 - 0x182bd5fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <b4614a68d1cb32a99ff638ddb1181ff4> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x182bd8000 - 0x182dddfff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <5c1540546de5350ab314c1d4c8a46d1b> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x182de0000 - 0x182df1fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <c46172ce833d398a8f1b54d22a4aaeaf> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x182df4000 - 0x18316cfff CoreFoundation arm64  <121118a9a44d3518b99f3ebfd8806f69> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x183170000 - 0x183180fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <bfee5e310ce439f0912635ac0bdbcaef> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x183184000 - 0x183184fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <913105a7ca583fed80e6b6329387bd34> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x183188000 - 0x1831f8fff IOKit arm64  <6dfdb62118f0357ba41ed63a66a5f0d6> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x1831fc000 - 0x18321bfff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <c9c425b7cc243ecfbb96c6b98a6737f9> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x18321c000 - 0x183306fff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <83e0d7a7234a3d93b70b33c650cce1c5> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x183308000 - 0x183375fff Security arm64  <32aa3c06560139de9fa54df2fd8605f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x183378000 - 0x1833d1fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <ede85de1bd2830518ea2caac42bad651> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x1833d4000 - 0x1834bcfff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <ac049ebda5c534d7a81fff7ff8924192> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x1834c0000 - 0x18374cfff CFNetwork arm64  <479946ecd173383d803077b338576727> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x183750000 - 0x18375dfff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <736f0f9f7b003dcbb91351472cedfd49> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x183760000 - 0x183779fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <6a0f886fe05d3250a030dd9256b14c08> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x18377c000 - 0x183796fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <8315a6fa429b3bc58da2a8d1cd259d61> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x183798000 - 0x1837c2fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <2558513a9240332998aa09cdbf49f3ec> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x1837c4000 - 0x1837e2fff libextension.dylib arm64  <b59c905587a63c9da06bfc8594ad8ae8> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x1837e4000 - 0x1837e5fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <49ce8afa64a033328e76f25af85ff4c4> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x1837e8000 - 0x183a55fff Foundation arm64  <9c53ce054a5630c98001ecd8fd71080a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x183a58000 - 0x183b03fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <c534306ddf9e3b90b25e1b66695b0dd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x183b04000 - 0x183e69fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <ca2b7c7ec1bb30b98c037998b26e01f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x183e6c000 - 0x1840c8fff vImage arm64  <a3390b9bac5135369964865d050a9b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1840cc000 - 0x1840eefff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <1dee62445ded325a93cfca54303bd378> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1840f0000 - 0x184104fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <0623251016ad33349829e232f4624c7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x184108000 - 0x184117fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <5d1851c74bd63cb1a1b6e4dfe8dc59cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x184118000 - 0x184184fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <7a83ca773be63bbbb33a8e8d1c2da9b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x184188000 - 0x184188fff vecLib arm64  <9008c7ee8a703d6faa091456a8990715> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x18418c000 - 0x18418cfff Accelerate arm64  <234dafe4fb09333a8bd23b74dff5670e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x184190000 - 0x1842fdfff CoreGraphics arm64  <b225beb40caf3521ad8af13986c9e25e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x184300000 - 0x184314fff GraphicsServices arm64  <9c0d8d96ee9a3abaa9ca2c1c83291ccd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x184318000 - 0x184360fff AppSupport arm64  <02b59c1c8da334a9852a3aa9bab98c07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x184364000 - 0x184425fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <afb0867c27e237b08d6fb64e1c44db59> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x184428000 - 0x184470fff BaseBoard arm64  <c5af56c0a45f3308932ffa68e609ccd8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x184474000 - 0x18447ffff AssertionServices arm64  <6be337b9a4ad3c72b1a9f5e48ac329db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x184480000 - 0x1844a1fff BackBoardServices arm64  <1098f9a35be63f4798089c25d613565c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x1844a4000 - 0x1844a7fff MobileSystemServices arm64  <7eb26bea09f53c1c9e8d732f9f8ba026> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x1844a8000 - 0x1844ddfff FrontBoardServices arm64  <c1c5ada9ceb03917892e043fee80857f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x1844e0000 - 0x1844eafff UserNotificationServices arm64  <e8dcb070485f38b699ef6b5decf244d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserNotificationServices.framework/UserNotificationServices
0x1844ec000 - 0x184511ff
```

Comment: An update
I found that is is actually caused by a bug in iOS 9.2
here is the official release from Apple https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205654

I was able to download the Beta version of iOS 9.2.1 from here and the push now works fine. https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/